# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 using Windows Azure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have an application that I'm working on that is supposed to use Azure SQL.  The solution builds fine without any errors but it can't find the SQL server. I keep getting this message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL    Server. The server was not found
>   or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

and it says my source error is this:

```
Line 73:  DbProviderServices services = DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(wrappedConnection);
Line 74: 
Line 75:  string token = wrapper.WrappedProviderInvariantName + ";" + services.GetProviderManifestToken(wrappedConnection);
Line 76:  return token;
Line 77:  }
```

I don't really understand what this means, as I haven't been working with ASP.NET, C#, or Azure long at all. Any help at all would be great.

Comment: Is this when you are running locally or deployed?

Comment: It happens when its deployed

Comment: Please post your connection string *(mask out credential and database name)*?

Comment: And you have an instance of SQL Azure running in that deployed environment? Is your application's config pointing to that instance in the cloud configuration?

Comment: <Setting name="DatabaseConnectionString" value="Server=tcp:******.database.windows.net; Database=; User ID=username@********; Password=XXXXXXXX; Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True;" />

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you allowed Windows Azure Serves, and enter IP Addresses *(if you want to access via SSMS)*.

For your scenario, I'll test it via SSMS first - just to make sure Instance name and credential are correct.

[image]